# Websphere Liberty : JMS Sessions don't work

Tags: jms, ejb, websphere-liberty

I am migrating EJB application from websphere 9.0 to Liberty. I am using the application server migration utility to help me with the migration. One of the listed issue is:

> Ported locally transacted JMS sessions do not work in Liberty

I checked the details mentioned in the help, but I could not understand much from the details.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you don't understand? It will help answerers to know how to guide you.

Answer (score 2):

JMS sessions in general will work in Liberty. However, *transacted* JMS sessions won't work. Therefore, applications using transacted JMS sessions which are ported to Liberty will not work as expected.

A transacted JMS session allows a client to collect different JMS operations (e.g. sending and consuming messages) into a single unit of work that is committed or rolled back atomically.

To be clear, a transacted JMS session uses what is sometimes called a "local" transaction because the transaction only applies to the specific JMS session involved. This is in contrast to a "global" transaction (sometimes called a "JTA" or "XA" transaction) which can involve many different kinds of resources (e.g. JMS, JDBC, etc.) and whose commit and roll-back is atomic across all those resources.

Comment: If you have a global transaction then the JMS work will be transacted and coordinated as required by the Java EE spec. What doesn't work is doing JMS local transactions using session.commit(), session.rollback() or the JMSContext equivalents.

Comment: Of course. I wasn't addressing global transactions. I was simply referring to transacted JMS sessions which is what the question was about. I'll update my answer to clarify this point.

Answer (score 1):

The JMS APIs provides methods for batching up multiple message sends and receives in a single transaction. These methods are intended for use in non-managed client environments. The way you do this is to create a transacted session (or JMSContext) and then call the commit or rollback methods.

In a managed environment the specification effectively says you can't do this and the transacted parameters be ignored. This is because if you do JMS work in a global transaction then the work needs to be coordinated with that transaction, so commit/rollback have no meaning.

The traditional WebSphere Application Server (for historic reasons), allows you to create a transacted JMS session and call commit and rollback outside of a global transaction (if you are inside it follows the spec mandated behaviour) when using IBM MQ.

The rule in question is looking for the creation of a transacted JMS session or JMSContext and reporting a possible issue.

If your code is running in a global transaction this is a false positive and you can ignore it. If you are running outside a global transaction and using the MQ JMS provider then you should review your code to do one of the following:

1. Move the code into a global transaction
2. Rewrite the code to stop relying on the commit/rollback methods